# Difficulties in developing for RSA SecurID

Tags: c#, .net, security, rsa, saas

I'm a product manager and not a developer so please be gentle if my question stupid.

I am currently trying to integrate our software with RSA SecurID, per a customer requirement (actually, like 20). For the record, I don't want to and I based on my research there are better and cheaper solutions out there, but I digress.

One of the issues we can into is that you cannot communicate directly with their Authentication Manager ("AM"). Instead, you have to use this RSA agent and send calls to the agent, which communicates with the AM. When you make calls to the agent, you also feed it file paths for specific files it needs that contain things it will need to communicate with the AM (cert, addresses, last state of AMs, etc.). Our software is shared SaaS and we can't just dump all of these customers files on the servers hard drive. Ideally, They need to be in the database, but the agent won't accept the files to be sent to it, like in an object, it expects them to be at a physical file path.

So my questions are:

- Has anyone else developed against RSAs SecurID solution?
- How did you handle storing the sdreq, nodesecret, etc.?
- In general, how would you handle the situation where you need to feed a program file paths while the file resides in a database (.NET)?

Comment: You can have the files stored in database and just before invoking the AM, write them to a temporary location.

Comment: Windows agent simply write the node secret to a file in `%WINDIR%\system32`. Write it anywhere that only an adminstrator can get to and encrypt it with DPAPI

Answer (score 5):

Implementing the SDTI protocol is not that hard, as long as you use the SDK. You will need some help from RSA. For example, [you need a valid licence just to download the SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12479950/591064), which you will get when you buy a server to test.

Supporting tokens also mean supporting some failure mode, like :

- tokens that have a clock skew (re-sync tokens)
- tokens that do not have a PIN (you must prompt for one)
- all the back and forth if the user does not provide valid information (ex: the new pin does not meet complexity requirements)

I suggest you implement the Radius protocol as a midway solution. All versions of Authentication Manager that I know also implement the Radius protocol. It is standardised and it has a chance of working with other solutions than SecurID. It could get you up and running faster and cheaper. Radius is somewhat weaker in terms of cryptographic protection over the wire, but you will not have to deal with node secrets.

On the other hand, you might have to do a little more work to support high availability, depending on the Radius client you select.

There are a few Radius .Net client libraries out there, and [this SO question is a good start](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8481898/591064).

Your test setup will include [NTRadPing](http://www.mastersoft-group.com/download/) and (I assume) a Server 2008 R2 with the Network Policy Role to act as a test server.