# Are the function signatures correct in the RSA Authentication Agent API documentation?

Tags: c, reverse-engineering, two-factor-authentication, securid

I have some software which uses the documented API for RSA's Authentication Agent. This is a product which runs as a service on the client machines in a domain, and authenticates users locally by communicating with an "RSA Authentication Manager" installed centrally.

The Authentication Agent's API is publicly documented here: [Authentication Agent API 8.1.1 for C Developers Guide](https://community.rsa.com/docs/DOC-36840). However, the docs seem to be incorrect, and I do not have access to the RSA header files - they are not public; only the PDF documentation is available for download without paying $$ to RSA. If anyone here has access to *up to date* header files, would you be able to confirm for me whether the documentation is out of date?

The function signatures given in the API docs seem incorrect - in fact, I'm absolutely convinced that they are wrong on x64 machines. For example, the latest PDF documentation shows the following:

```
int WINAPI AceSetUserData(SDI_HANDLE hdl, unsigned int userData)
int WINAPI AceGetUserData(SDI_HANDLE hdl, unsigned int *pUserData)
```

The documentation states several times that the "userData" value is a 32-bit quantity, for example in the documentation for `AceInit`, `AceSetUserData`, and `AceGetUserData`. A relevant excerpt from the docs for `AceGetUserData`:

> This function is synchronous and the caller must supply, as the second argument, a pointer to a 32-bit storage area (that is, an unsigned int) into which to copy the user data value.

This is clearly false - from some experimentation, if you pass in a pointer to the center of a buffer filled with 0xff, `AceGetUserData` is *definitely* writing out a 64-bit value, not a 32-bit quantity.

My version of `aceclnt.dll` is 8.1.3.563; the corresponding documentation is labelled "Authentication Agent API 8.1 SP1", and this corresponds to version 7.3.1 of the Authentication Agent itself.

#### Test code

Full test code given, even though it's not relevant to the problem at all... It's no use to me if someone else runs the test code (I know what it does!), what I need is someone with access to the RSA header files who can confirm the function signatures.

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>

#ifdef WIN32
#include <Windows.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#define SDAPI WINAPI
#else
#define SDAPI
#endif
typedef int SDI_HANDLE;
typedef uint32_t SD_BOOL;
typedef void (SDAPI* AceCallback)(SDI_HANDLE);
#define ACE_SUCCESS                    1
#define ACE_PROCESSING                 150

typedef SD_BOOL (SDAPI* AceInitializeEx_proto)(const char*, char*, uint32_t);
typedef int (SDAPI* AceInit_proto)(SDI_HANDLE*, void*, AceCallback);
typedef int (SDAPI* AceClose_proto)(SDI_HANDLE, AceCallback);

typedef int (SDAPI* AceGetUserData_proto)(SDI_HANDLE, void*);
typedef int (SDAPI* AceSetUserData_proto)(SDI_HANDLE, void*);

struct Api {
  AceInitializeEx_proto AceInitializeEx;
  AceInit_proto AceInit;
  AceClose_proto AceClose;
  AceGetUserData_proto AceGetUserData;
  AceSetUserData_proto AceSetUserData;
} api;

static void api_init(struct Api* api) {
  // All error-checking stripped...
  HMODULE dll = LoadLibrary(_T("aceclnt.dll")); // leak this for the demo
  api->AceInitializeEx = (AceInitializeEx_proto)GetProcAddress(dll, "AceInitializeEx");
  api->AceInit = (AceInit_proto)GetProcAddress(dll, "AceInit");
  api->AceClose = (AceClose_proto)GetProcAddress(dll, "AceClose");
  api->AceGetUserData = (AceGetUserData_proto)GetProcAddress(dll, "AceGetUserData");
  api->AceSetUserData = (AceSetUserData_proto)GetProcAddress(dll, "AceSetUserData");

  int success = api->AceInitializeEx("C:\\my\\conf\\directory", 0, 0);
  assert(success);
}

static void demoFunction(SDI_HANDLE handle) {
  union {
    unsigned char testBuffer[sizeof(void *) * 3];
    void *forceAlignment;
  } u;

  memset(u.testBuffer, 0xA5, sizeof u.testBuffer);

  int err = api.AceGetUserData(handle, (void*)(u.testBuffer + sizeof(void*)));
  assert(err == ACE_SUCCESS);

  fputs("DEBUG: testBuffer =", stderr);
  for (size_t i = 0; i < sizeof(u.testBuffer); i++) {
    if (i % 4 == 0)
      putc(' ', stderr);
    fprintf(stderr, "%02x", u.testBuffer[i]);
  }
  fputc('\n', stderr);
  // Prints:
  // DEBUG: testBuffer = a5a5a5a5 a5a5a5a5 00000000 00000000 a5a5a5a5 a5a5a5a5
  // According to the docs, this should only write out a 32-bit value
}

static void SDAPI demoCallback(SDI_HANDLE h) {
  fprintf(stderr, "Callback invoked, handle = %p\n", (void*)h);
}

int main(int argc, const char** argv)
{
  api_init(&api);
  SDI_HANDLE h;

  int err = api.AceInit(&h, /* contentious argument */ 0, &demoCallback);
  assert(err == ACE_PROCESSING);

  demoFunction(h);

  api.AceClose(h, 0);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: The things I'm particularly interested in: is SDI_HANDLE really an int (32-bit); what is the size of the userData argument in AceGetUserData/AceSetUserData/AceInit. By tedious experimentation I have determined that the other parameters in the API docs which are 32-bits do seem to be documented correctly.

Comment: Hmmm, even on 64-bit machine, `unsigned` is still often 32-bit.  Perhaps posting your sample code including that which reports `userData` and the output would be useful.  "AceGetUserData is definitely writing out a 64-bit value, not a 32-bit quantity" could be due to code subsequent to `AceGetUserData()`.

Comment: Yes, an int is basically always 32-bit (and certainly is on the Win/Mac/Linux arches we're looking at here). And the docs further make it super-explicit by saying the function writes out 32 bits of data.

I've added my test code, which clearly shows the function writing out 64  bits of data.

Comment: Nice addition UV. Using a valid pointer like `unsigned dummy = 42; int err = (*api.AceSetUserData)(handle, &dummy);` and printing it `fprintf(stderr, "DEBUG: dummy = [%p%p]\n", (void*) &dummy);` prior would remove the UB of using `(void*)0xdeadbeef12345678` and more clearly show the problem.  AFAIK, its the UB of `(void*)0xdeadbeef12345678`  hides the issue.

Comment: Why are you passing the address of a  `void*` in  `(*api.AceGetUserData)(handle, &testCanary[1])` instead of the address of a valid `unsigned`?  I'd expect `unsigned testCanary[3] = { -1u, -1u, -1u };
  err = (*api.AceGetUserData)(handle, &testCanary[1]);`

Comment: detail: There is a confusing grammar inconsistency in the post. "documentation states several times that the "userData" parameter is a 32-bit quantity" is followed by a contradictory "as the second argument, a _pointer_ to a 32-bit storage area".  From `AceGetUserData(SDI_HANDLE hdl, unsigned int *userData)`, `userData` is a _pointer_ of some bit size to an `unsigned` presumable 32-bit.  `userData` is not a 32-bit integer type.

Comment: I'm passing a `void**` to AceGetUserData, since with your example `unsigned testCanary[3]` it's actually going to do an unaligned 64-bit write - which succeeds on x64, but still... if we want to test whether a function is doing a 32-bit or 64-bit write, it just seems neater to pass a properly-aligned pointer. Re the UB: you're probably right that `(void*)0xdeadbeef12345678` is UB, but I'm compiling without optimizations - the fact that the full value is printed out subsequently shows the compiler's not doing anything surprising here (passing that literal value in a register to AceSetUserData).

Comment: Re: "There is a confusing grammar inconsistency in the post" - OK, I've made it a bit clearer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137080/discussion-between-chux-and-nicholas-wilson).

Comment: this question is about an external document, not about C so voting to close

Comment: @user3629249 Remove the C tag if you're convinced it's not relevant (although this is a C API) - but this is an answerable question about correct use of an API, and questions about specific 3rd party APIs are within the remit of StackOverflow.

Comment: I have _added_ the [reverse-engineering] tag, because, if I understand correctly, you have access to a particular DLL and to its documentation, but not to the associated C header files, and you're trying to work out how to call functions in there.

Answer (score 1):

As you've copied the function/type definitions out of the documentation, you basically don't have and never will have the correct definition for the version of the .dll you're using and could always end up in crashes or worse, undefined behavior.

What you could do is to debug the corresponding .dll:

Do you run Visual Studio? I remember that VS could enter a function call in debug mode and show the assembly, not sure though how it is today. But any disassembler should do the trick. As of [x64 ABI](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9z1stfyw.aspx) register `rcx` gets the first argument, `rdx` the second. If the function internally works with the 32bit register names or clears the upper 32bit than you can assume a 32bit integer. If it uses it to load an address (e.g. `lea` instruction) you could assume a pointer. But as you can see, that's probably not a road you wanna go down...

So what else do you have left?

The document you've linked states a 32-bit and 64-bit library - depending on the platform you use. I guess you use the 64bit lib and that RSA did not update the documentation for this library, but at some point the developers needed to upgrade the library to 64bit.

So think about this way: If you would be the API developer, what is possible to migrate to 64bit and what not. E.g. everything that needs to work across 32/64 implementations (stuff that gets send over the network or stored and shared on disk) cannot be touched. But everything that's local to the instance, can be migrated. As the `userData` seems to be a runtime thing, it makes sense to support whatever the platform provides: `unsigned long` on 64bit and `unsigned int` on 32bit.

You've figured out that `userData` must be 64 bit. But not because the function writes out a 64bit integer, but because the function sees a 64bit value to start with. As integers are passed by value (I guess in general, but definitely in [WINAPI](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zxk0tw93.aspx)), there's absolutely no chance the function could see the full 64bit value if it would be a 32bit datatype. So most likely, the API developers changed the datatype to `unsigned long` (in any case to 64bit type).

PS: If you end up putting a pointer into userData, cast the pointer to `uintptr_t` and store/read that type.

Comment: No, I don't have the headers! That's the point of the question. I've simply copied the function declarations that are given in the documentation.

Comment: @NicholasWilson Ah sorry, didn't catch that line that you've copied the definitions. I’ve updated the answer. Hope it can give you directions…

Comment: > "you basically don't have and never will have the correct definition for the version of the .dll you're using"
Surely the documentation should be right! There's nothing inherently wrong with loading symbols dynamically rather than statically linking to the library, as long as the function signature is correct.
I just want something who has the headers to check I've deduced the correct signature despite the bogus docs.

Comment: Well, as you experience, it's trial and error and no guarantee can be made about correctness of code. Even though it *seems* like your function signature is correct, there may still be subtle bugs that hit you only in rare circumstances. Regardless of that, you may want to rephrase/edit your question (why test code at all?), as you're not interested in solving a programming problem, but you look for header files. I doubt that SO is the right platform for that kind, though I can understand why you've tried. You may also want to try out reddit (/r/programming).

Answer (score 0):

To avoid questions of undefined behavior, please replace your test function with this one, and report what it prints.  Please also show us the *complete* test program, so that people who have access to this library can compile and run it for themselves and tinker with it.  I would especially like to see the declarations of the `api` global and its type, and the code that initializes `api`, and to know where the type came from (did you make it up as part of this reverse engineering exercise or did you get it from somewhere?)

```
static void demoFunction(SDI_HANDLE handle) {
  int err = api.AceSetUserData(handle, 0);
  assert(err == ACE_SUCCESS);

  union {
    unsigned char testBuffer[sizeof(void *) * 3];
    void *forceAlignment;
  } u;

  memset(u.testBuffer, 0xA5, sizeof u.testBuffer);

  err = api.AceGetUserData(handle, (void *)(u.testBuffer + sizeof(void*)));
  assert (err == ACE_SUCCESS);

  fputs("DEBUG: testBuffer =", stderr);
  for (size_t i = 0; i < sizeof(u.testBuffer); i++) {
    if (i % 4 == 0)
        putc(' ', stderr);
    printf(stderr, "%02x", u.testBuffer[i]);
  }
  fputc('\n', stderr);
}
```

(If your hypothesis is correct, the output will be

```
DEBUG: testBuffer = a5a5a5a5 a5a5a5a5 00000000 00000000 a5a5a5a5 a5a5a5a5
```

.)

Comment: You're right not to trust me, in case I've made some silly mistake, so I've updated the test code with a full file. There's no change. Originally I didn't post the demo code at all (until it was requested), because it's completely irrelevant to the question, which is what the correct function signature is (ie nothing to do with my code, and nothing that can be discovered by 'tinkering'). To answer your question, the types come from the official PDF documentation that's linked in the question, not through reverse-engineering. Thanks for the help though.

Comment: Thank you. At this point I think we can say conclusively that the documentation _is_ wrong. Indeed, it will be difficult to proceed further without access to the official headers. But you should be prepared for the possibility that the official headers are _also_ wrong.  This smells to me like a library that was never properly validated for use on a 64-bit operating system.